# How should I define a new command containing options for the use inside tikz-feynman environment?

Tags: tikz-feynman

I want to do the following stuff: say I have a diagram

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram{
            e1 --[momentum={[arrow distance=2mm]\(l\)}] we1;
        };
\end{document}
```

and I want to simplify the expression for options of momentum key, so I defined a command

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\newcommand{\mom}[2]{{[arrow distance=#1]\(#2\)}}
\begin{document}            
\feynmandiagram{
            e1 --[momentum=\mom{2mm}{l}] we1;
        };

\end{document}
```

Instead of reproducing the original diagram, the momentum label `l` becomes `[arrow distance=2mm]l`. The whole expression wasn't evaluated by tikz-feynman package and was taken as the momentum itself. How should I make this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of a `\newcommand` you can define a new style that accepts two arguments: `\tikzfeynmanset{mymomentum/.style 2 args={momentum = [arrow distance = #1] \(#2\) }}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{
    mymomentum/.style 2 args={ momentum={[arrow distance=#1]\(#2\)}}
              }

\begin{document}


\feynmandiagram{
            e1 --[mymomentum={2mm}{l}] we1;
        };
\end{document}
```

**Answer update** to consider OP new requirements

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{
    mymomentum/.code n args={3}{
    \def\tempa{#1}
    \def\tempb{#2}
    \def\tempc{#3}

    \ifx \empty\tempa 
      \pgfkeysalso{momentum/arrow distance={3mm}} % default value
    \else \pgfkeysalso{momentum/arrow distance={#1}}
    \fi

    \ifx \empty\tempb 
       \pgfkeysalso{momentum/arrow shorten={0.15}} % default value
    \else \pgfkeysalso{momentum/arrow shorten={#2}}
    \fi


    \pgfkeysalso{momentum={#3}}
              }}
\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram{
            e1 --[mymomentum={}{}{$l$}] we1;
        };

 \feynmandiagram{
            e1 --[mymomentum={5mm}{0.3}{$m$}] we1;
        };       
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to specify a default value for certain option? I was going to go with `xparse` but a simplest newcommand failed me.

Comment: @Turgon can you give me an example of what you need?

Comment: For example, I can call `mymomentum={l}` and the arrow distance will be assigned as `2mm` automatically. And if I add more options, i.e. `arrow shorten`, so that the whole option becomes `mymomentum={distance}{length}{l}`, and I call with `{distance}{l}`, `length` takes a default value.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I have one remaining question though. How should I assign which side the momentum arrow should be on, in the same way as adding prime to the `momentum` key?

Comment: @Turgon in a similar manner we can define a new  key `mymomentum'/.code n args ={...\pgfkeysalso{momentum'={#3}}}`